How to get current value of signal in Angular?
How to get current value of any signal in Angular?
E.g. I have the following compoent with a signal and I need to get its current value
class SomeComponent {
  age = signal<number>(20);

  void foo() {
    // how to get age's current value
  }
}


According to the docs you can read a signal's current value by calling its getter function.
Example:
class SomeComponent {
  age = signal<number>(20);

  void foo() {
    const currentAge = age();
    ...
  }
}

